# How to pass a list in a broken down format

Tags: c#, string, list

I was wondering if there was any way to pass a broken down list to a function. Here is my function.

```
public static void setp_R(List<string> stuff_to_add)
{
     Possible_res.Clear ();
     foreach(string a in stuff_to_add)
     {
         Possible_res.Add (a)
     }
}
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to hand it a broken down list.
such that instead of doing this...

```
List<string> thingstoadd = new List<string> ();
thingstoadd.Add ("Blah1");
thingstoadd.Add ("Blah2");
thingstoadd.Add ("Blah3");
setp_R (thingstoadd);
```

I could just do this...

```
setp_R (("blah1","blah2","blah3"));
```

I can't just make the function look like this...

```
public static void setp_R(string a1,string a2,string a3){}
```

because the function has to be flexible and needs to expand and shrink as more or less strings are put in.

And I have edit this list so much that it would be terrible to make Possible_res not a function.

Comment: What type is `Possible_res`? And by the way, you should follow the standard C# naming conventions. Variables shouldn't have underscores in the name, and you shouldn't use abbreviations unless they're well understood, such as `Html`. In this case, you might use a name like `possibleResolutions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` keyword:

```
public static void setp_R(params string[] stuff_to_add)
```

will do the trick.

If you don't want to change the signature, you can still shorten the list initialization code by using an initializer:

```
List<string> thingstoadd = new List<string> { "blah1", "blah2", "blah3" };
setp_R (thingstoadd);
```

or

```
setp_R (new List<string> { "blah1", "blah2", "blah3" });
```

Comment: Thank you this really is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Use `params` keyword:

```
public static void setp_R(params string[] stuff_to_add)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use params: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

```
public static void setp_R(params string[] stuff_to_add)
{
    Possible_res.Clear();
    foreach(string a in stuff_to_add)
    {
        Possible_res.Add (a)
    }
}
```

And use this like setp_R("something", "something else");